# How to create test fixtures for every example of a functional test

Tags: scala, playframework, functional-testing, specs2

Scala noob here.

I currently try to create functional tests for a Play (Scala) based web application using specs2. The examples themselves are simple, i.e.:

```
class SignInSpec extends PlaySpecification {

  // bring the workflow steps in scope and instrument browser with them    
  import utils.WorkflowSteps.AuthSteps

  "An activated user".should {
    "be able to sign in to the admin console" in new WithDbData(webDriver = WebDriverFactory(FIREFOX)) {

      // this should be: browser.signIn(testData.manager)
      // with the manager already persisted in the database
      browser.signIn(Manager(None, "me@home.com", "12341234", "John", "Doe", List("admin")))
    }
  }
}
```

What I'd like to achieve is to feed each example with a defined set of test data, some of which will already be persisted in the database. So I need a setup and a teardown method around each example that prepares a `TestData` case class, fills it with appropriate data and persists some of it so that the example can start with a defined database state.
Ultimately I want a plugin mechanism where the plugs defined the test data for a set of examples (think of it as an application of the loan pattern).

What I did so far:

- I tried to use some flavour of `Around`, but I don't know how to feed the data into the example as I'd have to add an additional return value.
- I tried specs2's ForEach context, but that conflicts with Play's WithBrowser
- I played with implicit vals, but again I don't know how to add an implicit parameter to the block that is transformed from a constructor to a function call parameter using `DelayedInit`

Any ideas how to proceed to achieve the following ?

- Extending the specification or the example from an additional trait or class that calls the example with a single parameter `TestData`
- This additional trait or class should be able to prepare test data and persist parts of it
- This additional trait or class should be compatible with `WithBrowser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is using so called "loan fixtures":

```
     def withTestData(test: TestData => Unit) = {
       val data = setupTestData() 
       try { 
         test(data)
       } finally {
         destroyTestData(data)
       }
     }



    "An activated user" should "be able to sign in to the admin console" in withTestData { data =>
       new WithDbData(webDriver = WebDriverFactory(FIREFOX)) {
         browser.signIn(data.manager)
       }
     }
```

etc ..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Dima. I got it to work so far that I can now create and persist the test data and it gets handed over to the example. There's still one problem, though: in case that preparing the test data fails (i.e. the db is unavailable) the test result is still positive, though it should be an error. Do you know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be the following:

```
 case class TestData(manager: Manager) extends WithDbData(webDriver = WebDriverFactory(FIREFOX))


 class SignInSpec extends PlaySpecification with ForEach[TestData] {

   // bring the workflow steps in scope and instrument browser with them    
   import utils.WorkflowSteps.AuthSteps

   "An activated user".should {
     "be able to sign in to the admin console" in { data: TestData =>
        import data._

        browser.signIn(manager)
     }
   }

   def foreach[R : AsResult](f: TestData => R): Result = ???
 }
```

This is at the expense of having to `import data._` but this also avoids the double nesting of the previous solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Eric. That would work, but it‘s rather awkward to have a data class implement test behaviour (WithDbData extends WithBrowser). The nesting is a problem, though, that I‘m still struggling with.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a case class, it can be `class TestData(val manager: Manager)`.